Pinia State not saved for components in different routes
When I mutate the Pinia state defined as an array (by pushing elements to it), I can't see the corresponding change from the component in another route.
The state changes can be checked in the same component, but I can't see the change from another component in another route.
The setup in the main.js file is the same as Pinia official document.
The following components are in Different routes.
Component 1 ( To initiate the change )
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import DisplayQueue from './DisplayQueue.vue'
import { useQueueStore } from '@/store/QueueStore'

const { bizType } = defineProps(['bizType'])
const waitingCount = ref(0)
const currentNum = ref(0)
const listRef = ref(null)
const queueStore = useQueueStore()
const handleClick = () => {

  currentNum.value += 1
  queueStore.add({
    type: bizType,
    currentNum: currentNum.value
  })
  waitingCount.value = queueStore.getQueueWithType(bizType).length
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="">
    <div class="card" @mousedown="handleClick">
      <p class="title">{{ title }}</p>
      <p>等待人數：{{ waitingCount }}人</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Component 2 ( To see the change )
<script setup>

import { useQueueStore } from '@/store/QueueStore'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const queueStore = useQueueStore()
const { queue } = storeToRefs(queueStore)

</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="numberCard in queue" :key="numberCard.currentNum">
      <div class="place-items">
        <span>{{ numberCard.type }}</span>
        <span>{{ numberCard.currentNum }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Pinia Store
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useQueueStore = defineStore('queue', {
  state: () => ({
    queue: []
  }),
  getters: {
    getQueue() {
      return this.queue
    },
    getQueueWithType: (state) => (queueType) => {
      return state.queue.filter((item) => item.type === queueType)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    add(item) {
      this.queue.push(item)
    },
    remove() {
      this.queue.shift()
    }
  }
})



Update

I have confirmed with Vue devtool that the store ONLY changes correctly in the page showing component 1.

However, the store seems to be untouched in the other page.


Update 2

I use vue-router for navigation. I put 2 router links targeting two components mentioned above in home view.
Here are my router file and home view file.
Router file
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '@/views/HomeView.vue'
import ProcessView from '@/views/ProcessView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/display',
      name: 'display',
      component: () => import('../views/DisplayView.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/process',
      name: 'process',
      component: ProcessView
    }
  ]
})

export default router


Home view
<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <nav>
    <RouterLink to="/process">component 1</RouterLink>
    <RouterLink to="/display">component 2</RouterLink>
  </nav>
</template>



have you used Vue devtools to verify the store is correctly updated?  Do any errors appear in console?  the code shown seems fine.  you might need to provide a runnable MCVE that can be debugged.

Yes, I've confirmed the store only changes in the page showing component 1. There are no errors showing in console.

how do you navigate between pages?  are you using router-link?  something like an <a> link can cause full page reload which will cause pinia to reset.  look for full page reload problem somewhere in your navigation.

I use vue router for navigation because I'm aware of the effect of using <a> tag, which is exactly what you've mentioned. However, it seems luck is not on my side even without using <a> tag.

Try adding a console.log in your app's root component (probably App.vue).  if the console.log is seen when navigating then that's confirmation you have a full page reload happening. It will take more code/debugging to figure out why. As a workaround you can use a plugin or other strategy to persist your data across reloads.
